# How to get layout not reload when redirect page?

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm using a layout name "`layout_default.xml`" each controller in my module.

Can I make magento not to reload that layout when I redirect to another controller?

I call `layout_default` by using

```
<update handle="layout_default"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like this is possible! The layout will be render when redirect so there is noway to do this.